# Change tor proxy by tor control protocol

Tags: php, proxy, controls, tor

I want to change automaticaly tor proxy settings in PHP through tor control protocol, but I don't know the appropriate command to do that.
I tried :

```
GETCONF HTTPProxyAddr
```

or

```
GETCONF HTTPProxyPort
```

but tor answered :

```
510 Unrecognized command
```

What are the keywords to control the proxy used in front of tor?
Thanks

Comment: I have never heard of these PHP commands or constructs in my entire life as a PHP programmer. Also, why do you want to do this programmatically? The Tor button should let you do this quite easily via GUI

Comment: I'm talking about the tor control protocol

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to regenerate a tor route is `SIGNAL NEWNYM`. Here's some quick sample code:

```
<?php
    $sock = fsockopen( 'unix://control' );
    fwrite( $sock, "AUTHENTICATE\n" );
    echo fread( $sock, 128 );
    fwrite( $sock, "SIGNAL NEWNYM\n" );
    echo fread( $sock, 128 );
?>
```

Look at [Section 3.7 of the Control Specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=control-spec.txt).

Note that the proxy address and port stay the same and never change. It's the route that is changed. If you want to authenticate and grab the proxy address and port via control issue a `GETCONF`.

However, `HTTPProxyAddr` is not a valid configuration variable, `HTTPProxy` is. A list of all configuration variables can be found here https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en. Some versions of Tor did throw a 510 when an incorrect configuration variable was requested.